# Upgrading to TFS 2015 - copying a project

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

HELP!!

I'm learning on the fly here with no training whatsoever!  I'm a system administrator who is responsible for supporting the developers.  They use Visual Studio, TFS, Plastic SCM and TeamCity amongst other tools.

My task was to get TFS 2015 and SQL Server 2014 installed on a new VM.  This I have done but my biggest task now is setting up TFS which seems complicated.

For your information, The developers use TFS 2012 as a Kanban board.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to documentation that simply explains how to copy a project from one collection to another?  I'm reluctant to move the project to the new version of TFS without testing the current project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy a single project, there is the [TFS integration platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), but it sucks and doesn't officially support TFS 2015

I would say your best bet is to follow the following steps.

1. In TFS 2012, detach the collection using the TFS Admin Console.
2. Backup the collection database in SQL server
3. Copy the backup to the new SQL server
4. Restore the Database
5. In the TFS Admin Console in TFS 2015, attach the collection
6. Wait for TFS to update the Database Schema.

You should now have the full team project collection available in the new server.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  On point 4, does that mean I will still have TFS 2012 working as it was?

Comment: If you re-attach the collection (between points 2 and 3) then TFS 2012 will continue to work. You can then practice the process till you are happy it works